# How to run celery in django tests using PyCharm

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pycharm, celery

I'm trying to test my Django application functionalities.
Some of my tasks are using Celery.
How can I run celery in my test environment using PyCharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're using the shared_task decorator and running the tasks as function_name.delay()

This could be tested by adding a conditional that runs the task if running locally (or via a test) and uses celery in production. This also allows one to run the server locally without using celery, and that can be easier to debug and maintain.

```
PRODUCTION = False

if PRODUCTION:
    some_task.delay()
else:
    some_task()
```

One could also create a decorator that does the same thing, which is prettier, but perhaps more complicated to maintain?

Comment: Your assumptions are right and I should mentioned those details!

Answer (score 2):

To do unit tests without testing the celery stuff you may want to mock your @shared_task decorator

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('celery.shared_task', lambda *args, **kwargs: lambda func: func)
def test_celery_unit()
    from tasks import mytask
    result = mytask() # could be call just as a function
```

Answer (score 0):

using [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) library will solve your problem.